# How to add a integer field to date field in maximo?

Tags: date, date-arithmetic, maximo

I need to add a integer field to the date field then output value should be in date format.

For Eg: frequency is integer field and certdate is date field i wrote a Set Value action in which I need to set the summation of both values to the Nextdate field(Date) and i am using db2.

Answer (score 0):

If having a Value of `:certdate + :frequency` and a Parameter/Attribute of NEXTDATE isn't working for you, you'll need to revert to an automation script or Java class that uses the Date and Calendar classes to do what you want.

Comment: Thank You. I wrote the query as (:frequency days + :asset.certdate) the same query is working in db(sql developer) but when i put this in Maximo Expression builder an db error is showing up